# How can I access and change variable in concatenated text of tooltip using D3/javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

How can I set up a D3 tooltip so that I can style pieces of text from variables (or just the JSON children) differently?

I have created a tooltip that pulls text from a JSON file (beginning context, a word, end context) when you click on a node. I would like to style the middle element differently (e.g. make it bold, bigger, etc.). If I add .attr or .style to the variable I get a ".attr is not a function" error. I'm still quite new and appreciate any tips you have!

Here's the relevant snippet:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()  
        .style('opacity', 1)

      var word = d.word
        .style("font-size", 60 + "px");

      tooltip.html(d.beginContext + " " + word + " " + d.endContext)
        .style('left', 1100 + "px")
        .style('top',  250 + 'px');
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
{"node": "",
  "children": [
  {
    "name":"cat",
    "location":141470,
    "beginContext":"cried; 'canna we be quick?'\n\nBut speed was not in Mrs. Marston. She came clinging to Edward's arm, very cautiously, like a",
    "word":"cat",
    "endContext":"on ice.\n\nMartha, her stout red arms bare, her blue gingham dress and white apron flying in the wind, was directed to hold on to Mrs"
  },
  {
    "name":"birds",
    "location":143666,
    "beginContext":"heard and blessed again. To Hazel, they seemed so many other Hazels singing because it was a festal day. To Mrs. Marston they were 'noisy",
    "word":"birds",
    "endContext":", and very disturbing.' Martha crotcheted. She was making edging, hundreds of yards of it, for wedding garments. This was all the more creditable"
  }]}
```

You can also view the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/westcoast_509/ofcqq8r0/): http://jsfiddle.net/westcoast_509/ofcqq8r0/ (scroll right or zoom out to see the text appear on click).

Comment: Can you update the fiddle so that it can actually work?

Comment: Updated fiddle--it just had a https on it. Changed to http. Should work swimmingly now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a updated example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ofcqq8r0/18/

I have added the CSS classes:

```
.text-large {
     font-size: 80px;
}
```

And I have modified the JS code on the place where you do positioning of comment div:

```
var word = '<span class="text-large">' + d.word + '</span>';
```

I think that everything is clear but please ask me if you have some doubts.
Also since you are hardcoding the `'left'` and `'top'`inside of JS, you should move that to CSS also.

Additionally you can make even more detailed and specific styles, it is limited just by your imagination.

Comment: I think my question isn't quite clear (and I'm not sure how to ask it). I don't want the entire tooltip to be styled differently according to selection. I want the word only to be styled differently than the context. e.g. When I saw the BIRD, I knew it. (where "bird" is the word, and "when..." and "I knew it" are the beginning and end contexts. Does that make sense?

Comment: So you only need to style the value of property 'word' lets say it is 'Bird' differently?

Comment: Yes! Basically I want to make it appear larger than its context. I'm looking for a generalizable solution (rather than hard coding) b/c I have about a dozen more of these visualizations to make, and some of them have hundreds of nodes. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That did it! Thanks so much! I just had the thought to add a span seconds before I checked your answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I am not very familiar with D3, but I imagine you could do something like this:

Javascript:

```
.on("click", function(d) {
      tooltip.transition()  
        .style('opacity', 1)

      var word = d.word
        .style("font-size", 60 + "px")
        .style(d.extraStyleName, d.extraStyleValue);

      tooltip.html(d.beginContext + " " + word + " " + d.endContext)
        .style('left', 1100 + "px")
        .style('top',  250 + 'px');
```

Then in your JSON:

```
{"node": "",
  "children": [
  {
    "name":"cat",
    "location":141470,
    "beginContext":"cried; 'canna we be quick?'\n\nBut speed was not in Mrs. Marston. She came clinging to Edward's arm, very cautiously, like a",
    "word":"cat",
    "extraStyleName":"color",
    "extraStyleValue":"red",
    "endContext":"on ice.\n\nMartha, her stout red arms bare, her blue gingham dress and white apron flying in the wind, was directed to hold on to Mrs"
  },
  {
    "name":"birds",
    "location":143666,
    "beginContext":"heard and blessed again. To Hazel, they seemed so many other Hazels singing because it was a festal day. To Mrs. Marston they were 'noisy",
    "word":"birds",
    "extraStyleName":"color",
    "extraStyleValue":"green",
    "endContext":", and very disturbing.' Martha crotcheted. She was making edging, hundreds of yards of it, for wedding garments. This was all the more creditable"
  }]}
```

Alternatively you could assign one or more CSS class names, using D3's [classed method](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#classed).

Comment: I'm afraid javascript gives me the ".style is not a function" error when I try to add it (or .attr) under the var word = d.word (as I explained above). Same goes for classed. I'm not sure why.